# How can I display the name of the user who modified my doc word with option "track changes" off

Tags: microsoft-word, change-tracking

I am a French writer (sorry for the spelling mistakes). I have given a confidential manuscript to a professional editor in order to correct it. It seems that the guy has forwarded the doc to a non-allowed person who edited it instead of him. The editor sent it back to me with the option "track changes" off. Therefore I cannot know who has done what (and what has been done). I am working with the latest version of Word for mac (2016 "version 15.24"). It seems that what I am asking for is impossible. I find it strange that Microsoft gives plenty of details on their website to remove "sensitive meta-data" but nothing to find them back (the side they choose is quite clear)... Many thanks in advance. If someone could help me, I would be extremely grateful, 
Anne

Comment: I use microsoft 2016 (office 2016) for mac

Answer (score 1):

You could compare documents to find out what changed. On a Mac, that is Tools > Track Changes. It is not a perfect tool, but works well. If you have photos and images in your document, you will want to check those manually.

[image: Track changes on Mac]

Unfortunately, this does not solve the question of **who** exactly did what.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of changes you should either lock the whole document with a Password and just allow changes to text content this way the File it self Metadata e.g. is protected and the change of the track changes feature is also locked (but this may be no longer possible in current versions on my old office 2000 i think it worked that way)

But to be honest with you these feature at all wasn't introduced for what you're using it. It is meant to be used if there are multiple People (with the same trust level) working on the same Document. In your Case where you don't trust the other one this feature doesn't help you at all since Word uses the Name set on the Account for Annotation and as you may guess one can create Fake Account Microsoft doesn't even verify if the Account Name one chooses matches ones Real Name

What you need is a DMS Document Management System or GED in French [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestion_électronique_des_documents](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestion_%C3%A9lectronique_des_documents)